# How to set up WiFi on Ubuntu 19.10 Server running on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 Server on my Raspberry Pi 4. This seems to be working mostly fine but I am unsure how to connect to WiFi through it's terminal-only interface.

I've seen a few instructions on various articles and forums but they all seem to be reliant on downloading things to do the job, which I can't do without WiFi.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit vague. Ubuntu should have `nmcli` preinstalled - is it?. How do you currently access it? Do you want to set it up in the running system or change config files when accessing the flash drive from another PC?

Comment: `nmcli` was not pre-installed unfortunately. This was a completely fresh OS installation so I have not accessed wifi on it before. Changing config files from another computer would probably be preferred. However, I have now resorted to plugging into the router. It would be interesting to understand how to connect to wifi from the command line without plugging in for the future though :)

Comment: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/connect-to-wi-fi-from-terminal-on-ubuntu-18-04-19-04-with-wpa-supplicant - this article helped me.

Comment: `iwconfig` and lots of other tools from the "linuxbabe" article are not installed in RPI image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should check the netplan program, available at least since ubuntu bionic 18.04, and also included on the base image.

For the wireless configuration, you may follow the example:

`/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml`

Probably you want to enable the dhcp configuration and remove the static parts. Just copy the example to the `/etc/netplan/` directory and edit it, so it may looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      access-points:
        "<your network ESSID>":
          password: "<your wifi password>"
```

Later you execute the netplan with:

```
sudo netplan try
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. I use this way to enable wifi for installing ubuntu 19.10 on a respberry pi 4. It works smoothly :)

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do it without keyboard and screen? For raspbian you just add wpa_supplicant.conf but it doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu.